# Difficulty serving Swagger API documentation in Falcon with falcon-swagger-ui

Tags: python, rest, swagger, falconframework

I'm trying to serve swagger API docoumentation based on the falcon-swagger-ui package: https://github.com/rdidyk/falcon-swagger-ui
and using the example in the repo I have:

```
# example.py
import falcon
from falcon_swagger_ui import StaticSinkAdapter
from falcon_swagger_ui import register_swaggerui_app

SWAGGERUI_URL = '/swagger'  
SCHEMA_URL = '/swagger.json'

app = falcon.API()
app.add_sink(
    StaticSinkAdapter('/home/greg/falcon-swagger-example/schema.json'), SCHEMA_URL
)

register_swaggerui_app(app, SWAGGERUI_URL, SCHEMA_URL, config={
    'supportedSubmitMethods': ['get'],
})
```

where my schema json files already exist. if I then run `gunicorn example:app` and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/swagger I get the following error:

```
[2017-11-30 13:51:59 +0000] [23935] [ERROR] Error handling request /swagger.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/greg/falcon-swagger-example/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/home/greg/falcon-swagger-example/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/home/greg/falcon-swagger-example/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/falcon/api.py", line 242, in __call__
    responder(req, resp, **params)
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?
Is there a better package in anyone's opinion for serving swagger API documentation with a Falcon API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the original post there have been a few updates to falcon-swagger-ui.

Now if you use the example in the repo:

https://github.com/rdidyk/falcon-swagger-ui/blob/master/example.py#L9-L17

and place your swagger schema in static/v1/swagger.json then the swagger will be shown correctly when you head to http://127.0.0.1:8000/swagger